# how to insert same LAST_INSERT_ID() in one table to create multiple records;

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am programming a website, with ASP.NET, C#, as well as using MYSQL.
I need to be able to record two rows with same child_id;

My problem is with this one statement, it inserts one row and skips the last.

```
   //data.ChldrenRecord.Service contain two records
   // babysit, and tutor
  foreach (string s in data.ChildrenRecord.Services)
  {
     query += (" INSERT INTO ServiceChildren SET service='" + s + "', child_id=LAST_INSERT_ID();");
  }
```

so table should look something like this

```
 id   service    child_id
 1    babysit    1
 2    tutor      1
```

I use Last_INSERT_ID() because child_id is a foreign key. I create a record in another table whose primary key is child_id. Afterwards, I use LAST_INSERT_ID() to reference that one record primary key child_id so that i may use it in my ServiceChildren table.

as it stands my table looks:

```
 id    service   child_id
 1     babysit   1
```

I think i am on the right track now. if i log directly into the database, this statement works:

```
  SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
 //then insert statements
  INSERT INTO ServiceChildren(service, child_id) VALUES('babysit', @last_id);
  INSERT INTO ServiceChildren(service, child_id) VALUES('tutor', @last_id);
```

BUT IN MY C#, ASP.NET CODE THE LINE 
       **SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();**
does not do anything, even populate tables with a prior insert statement.

Comment: Get the LAST_INSERT_ID value from the previous query and use that value in your loop. However consider to switch ASAP to a parameterized query. String concatenation is just a disaster waiting to happen (Read about Sql Injection)

Comment: By the way, you are using  the syntax for an UPDATE. That will never work with an INSERT statement

Comment: i had to use string concatenation because i couldn't find the right parameterized query to use in ASAP.  i know this because it kept plugging in '@Service' instead of babysit or tutor.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out my problem. I needed to place **Allow User Variables=True** in the connection string to be allowed to create and use **@last_id**.